# Restart (entire) program function Python 3.5

Tags: python

How do I make a function which can restart my entire program, without using a while loop......

I have tried and tried again (many times) and have not been able to make it work with a GUI (tkinter)

Comment: What you are asking is not clear at all please provide an example of your code with something you tried

Comment: Restarting the entire process host seems unnecessary.  Instead, focus on managing the state of your application and simply set that to a known initial state in code.  Since we know *nothing* of your application, we can't really tell you how to do that.

Comment: Do you _really_ need to completely restart the application, or do you just need to reset the internal state? Restarting is possible (and fairly easy) but it seems rather drastic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [execl](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/os.html#os.execl), which replaces the current process with a new process. You can give it the exact same arguments as the current process, effectively restarting your program:

```
import sys, os
python = sys.executable
os.execl(python, python, * sys.argv)
```

Pay close attention to the documentation: this function does not return, and it doesn't close any connections or open files. Make sure you prepare your app for an immediate exit before calling.

Comment: This won't work on Windows if Python is installed in a path with spaces.

Answer (score 0):

You can use os.execl for this purpose.
There's a snippet over [here](https://www.daniweb.com/programming/software-development/code/260268/restart-your-python-program-)

You can find more information about those functions in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.execl)